# AngularJS change scope variable on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, controller

I try to set a scope variable within a template on `ng-click` and later read it in the controller. Example:

HTML:

```
<section id="editCtrl" data-ng-controller="EditCtrl as edit">
    {{ edit.myVar = []; "" }}
    Click the following buttons:<br>
    <span data-ng-click="edit.myVar['entry'] = 'test'">Click me</span>
    <span data-ng-click="edit.showMyVar();">Show MyVar in console</span>
</section>
```

JS:

```
// This controller is just for the example - I would never add a controller variable within the template
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("EditCtrl", function(){
    var edit = this;
    edit.showMyVar = function(){
        console.log(edit.myVar);
    };
});
```

However the variable "edit.myVar" keeps beeing an empty array. What am I doing wrong? In my interpretation this is a valid ng-click expression.

**Live example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7mv4t51/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of changes you have to do --

> You can not keep an assignment code in `{{ }}` since this code renders
>   frequently . so you will not get the actual value.

[Working plunker..](http://plnkr.co/edit/Et0Ca2zFAo6xSnEzdRJC?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>span:nth-of-type(1){background:yellow;}
      span:nth-of-type(2){background:red;}</style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="editCtrl" ng-controller="EditCtrl as edit">
    Click the following buttons:<br>
    <button ng-click="edit.myVar['entry']='test'">Click me</button>
    <button ng-click="edit.showMyVar()">Show MyVar in console</button>
      </section>
      <script>angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'])</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Js file**

```
 // This controller is just for the example - I would never add a controller variable within the template
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("EditCtrl", function(){
    var edit = this;
    edit.showMyVar = function(){
        alert(JSON.stringify(edit.myVar));
    };
});
```

**Problems with your code :**

1. You can not keep an assignment code in `{{ }}` since this code renders frequently . so you will not get the actual value.
2. one more problem at my end before loading document app was bootstraping.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the brackets in `ng-click`?

Comment: fiddle could not be forked you can check snippet added @julmot

Comment: This is the working fiddle link with your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ug9j9ome/1/

Comment: Thank your for your help! Finally could you please reply to my question?

Comment: I can not assign any variable without brackets but I can call a function without? This seems to be strange for me...

Comment: no bracket was wrong , since with bracket code renders frequently when digest cycle runs

Comment: Yes you are right... Could you explain this? I think this is the important point in this thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84182/discussion-between-nglover-and-julmot).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `edit.myVar = {'entry' : ''};` in controller first like this

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("EditCtrl", function(){
    var edit = this;
    edit.myVar = {'entry' : ''};; // initailize the array here
    edit.showMyVar = function(){
        console.log(edit.myVar);
    };
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

Note:

> first click on the 'click me' span and value is set into the array
>   and click on the next span for your console it.  your console only
>   works on clicking `edit.showMyVar();` function

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n7mv4t51/1/)

[image]

Comment: This does not work in Firefox because it should be an object instead of an array.

Comment: @julmot - I update my answer it will work on all browsers\

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<section id="editCtrl" ng-init="edit.myVar = [];" data-ng-controller="EditCtrl as edit">
Click the following buttons:<br>
<span data-ng-click="edit.myVar['entry'] = 'test'">Click me</span>
<span data-ng-click="edit.showMyVar();">Show MyVar in console</span>
```

Update: I think your object was getting initialized again and again. I used ng-init method so it will initialize object only once.

Comment: This does not change anything. Also you should explain why this would solve the problem,

Comment: I have edited my comment. I hope you have tried this solution.